# Multiple logins

Tags: flutter, mobile

I want to make a hotel booking app for mobile and web with 4 different login rights. I have confused that which way is better making a different app for different logins, or a single app with multiple logins.

Answer (score 1):

It's a trade off.

If you app is such that you want completely different behavior for each login with only a few similarities then considering different app for different login might not be as bad.

But if your app is such that you have a lots of similarities with extra added functionality for each login, single app might be a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

You are making a hotel booking app and you have 4 different user types.
So, according to my experience first of all you have to analyze

-> What is the functionality of all users?

-> UI is similar for all users or not.

-> If you will make a single screen for all users then you have to hide and show things based on your user type so lots of conditions will come in a single page. It will manageable?

-> Suppose, In the future, you want to add a new functionality user wise then you are able to add them, and your app should expandable to add new user roles also.

So, these are some parameters for example to take care of.

You have to think on your own, cover the whole app functionality and focus on the common parts of the app and different parts of the app.

And last take a decision about what will be the better for you. Separate App or Differnt App.

Thank you.